I cant run and fit this ai model : cnnbilst
enter image description here
error code
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_31' (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "time_distributed_167" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 384, 1), found shape=(200, 384, 1, 1)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_31' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(200, 384, 1), dtype=float64)
  • training=True
  • mask=None

i know this error occur because input shape.. but i dont know how to fix...
